# Exibir a categoria publicada em post type no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, framework

Como faço para exibir a categoria cadastrada em um post type no Wordpress?

Estou utilizando o Odin Framework, criei um `post type` chamado produtos e gostaria de exibir a categoria junto ao post.

Ex: Postado em 06 de julho de 2017 na categoria Geladeiras.

Nos posts do blog, para exibir as categorias é utilizado o seguinte código:

```
<?php echo __( 'Posted in:', 'odin' ) . ' ' . get_the_category_list(); ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Não sei bem como funciona o seu framework, mas usando algumas funções do WP pode fazer isso de várias formas:

```
$categoria = get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->name;
```

Ref:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var
- https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars

---

```
$categoria = get_cat_name( $cat_id );
```

Ref:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_name

---

Qualquer coisa dê uma lida nesse [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-the-current-category-name-inside-the-loop), trata sobre um caso semelhante ao seu.

Comment: Encontrei uma possível solução, mas agora ele está exibindo categorias que o produto não pertence.

Ex: Ex: Tenho dois produtos, geladeira e fogão, a categoria geladeira tem várias subcategorias, então marco todas elas e a categoria da televisão tem somente uma. Quando acesso o produto televisão, ele lista a categoria das geladeiras também, por que isso acontece ?

Categoria: Geladeira, pequena, televisão...


Código usado: http://pastebin.com/8e4d7Bn8